# What is the better way of writing this query?

Tags: sql

I have a simple join query as follows.

```
select * 
from user u left join 
     user_roles ur 
     on  ur.user_id = u.user_id 
     and ur.created_by = 'Mike'
where u.division = 'some division'
```

OR

```
select * 
from user u left join 
     user_roles ur 
     on  ur.user_id = u.user_id 
where u.division = 'some division' 
and   ur.created_by = 'Mike'
```

The point is here is I have moved the additional filter clause condition from left join to where clause.

Does it make any difference if I join two tables on more than column or put it in where clause?

Comment: in your first query it will return all roles and in second your left outer join is working like inner join.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it makes a big difference.

You are basicalling nullifying the left join and making it an inner join, hiding user roles not created by Mike

```
Bell Mike
Toe Mike
Bob Jerry
```

first query returns

```
Bell Mike
Toe Mike
Bob NULL
```

second Query returns

```
Bell Mike
Toe Mike
```

Comment: @BobTodd. So my first query is incorrect as i want the output you have shown for second query.

Comment: @anything you should use an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @anything you can then change your query to use `inner join`

Comment: @anything well yeah the fact that u are saying a user role must be created by 'Mike', means a division must have a user role with a creator, suggests it should be an inner join as there's no conditional

Comment: @BobTodd. Ok. What will happen if I use inner join instead of left join in both the queries? Will two return the same result? WHich will be more efficient?

Comment: @anything - yep - an educated guess would be that the query optimiser will spit them out identically

Answer (score 4):

Yes - it makes an important difference

Any filter on the joined table should be in the join for it to work correctly - ie: the former will work, the second won't.

Try the following (SQL Server syntax) to see how the results differ

```
declare @u table (user_id int, division varchar(20))
declare @ur table (user_id int, created_by varchar(10))

insert @u values (1,'sales'), (2,'marketing'), (3,'engineering')

insert @ur values (1, 'mike'), (3,'james'), (3,'mike')

select * from @u u  
left join @ur ur on ur.user_id = u.user_id and ur.created_by = 'Mike' 

select * from @u u  
left join @ur ur on ur.user_id = u.user_id 
where ur.created_by = 'Mike'
```